# Run a 12 dc power through telephony cable

Tags: power, dc

I have a converter (120 AC to 12 DC) which is used for sending alert to outdoor through 30 meters telephony cable. My quistion is ( Is it harmful if someone touch the cable? the output can give up to 20 amp.

Comment: I really, _really_ doubt that standard telephone cable can handle 20 amps.

Comment: Hire an electrician before you hurt yourself or others.

Comment: I am an electric technician and i now how to deal with it. My enquiry is it safe or not?

Comment: If you don't know whether it's safe or not, then you don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: As an electric technician ( electrical technician) you should be capable of calculating this yourself, aware of the limits based on the cable, capable of selecting the correct cable for the task AND the environment ie getting the job done safely to the required standard.

Comment: Gentlemen, it seems you don't got me very well.

Comment: Actually, I received an ENG package to be implementing then i asked here just to confirm my opinion.

Comment: it is not harmful to touch the cable because  the cable is insulated .....  you should really try to ask a clear question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe 20A is just your supply which is irrelevant. What is the load?

Let's see, Telephone cable which is AWG 24 which is 10 Ohms per hundred meters. If you use 4 wire as 2 + 2 then it becomes 5 Ohms/100m and then 10 both round trip.

So loop resistance is 3 Ohms for 30 Meters so with a 10% tolerance on 12V or 1.2V /3 Ohms = 400mA and you have a 20A supply which has no added value unless you can adjust it higher or use a 19V laptop charger to get 12V at the other end then you have 7V drop/3 ohms to get 2.33 Amps

A short circuit on 12V/3 Ohm produces 4 Amps and 48 Watts of heat which would make the wires hot. IN free air 3.5A is allowed. Enclosed only 2.1A is allowed for safe operation.

Comment: Alen, you're welcome